# How to get the URL referrer in a C# Browser Helper Object (BHO)?

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, bho

I am writing a Browser Helper Object (BHO) for Internet Explorer. The BHO should get the URL of the current website as well as the referrer. Here is the relevant code snippet from my BHO.cs file:

```
public class BHO:IObjectWithSite
{

    SHDocVw.WebBrowser webBrowser;

    public void OnDocumentComplete(object pDisp, ref object URL)
    {

        if (!ReferenceEquals(pDisp, webBrowser))
        {
            return;
        }
        string url = URL.ToString();
        // now the relevant line
        string referrer = HttpRequest.UrlReferrer;
        // more code

    }
}
```

`string referrer = HttpRequest.UrlReferrer;` [does no work](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer(v=vs.100).aspx), as I understand it is for aspx pages, but not for "pure" C# files. So, is there a way to get the referrer in this case? (For example, in JavaScript it is possible in a browser extension to use var referrer = document.referrer; in the context of the current page and get the referrer.) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try get on httpcontext.Current

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried string referrer = HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri; and variations thereof, but that did not work (however, it also did not show any error).